# Using only .loc[], how can you extract a single index-column in a multi-indexed df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, pandas-loc

I know there are many posts on the general theme of extracting a single index-column from a multi-indexed df. I hope this question can be differentiated, as I haven't found something answering this narrower point.

But basically, say I have a multi-indexed df, test2

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'credit_score': [608, 607, 502, 699, 850], 'age': [42, 41, 42, 39, 43], 'exited': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'], 'surname': ['Hargrave', 'Hill', 'Hill', 'Boni', 'Mitchell'], 'geography': ['France', 'Spain', 'France', 'France', 'Spain']})
test2 = test.set_index(['credit_score', 'age'])
```

If I wanted to extract (as an array, series with default index, or index object) a single index-column from test2 ('age') via .loc, i.e., using *only* test2.loc[fill_in_code], how could I do that?

I know about alternative methods, like .query(), .get_level_values(), etc., But I'm trying to get a better sense of how versatile .loc alone is. Explanation or links to explanations are appreciated.

Comment: Hi, so you want to extract "age" from test2 index using only `loc` accessor?

Comment: Yes, extracted into one object form or another. I was curious how/if this is possible